# How to efficiently update the API when Swagger spec file is updated? (express, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I'm trying to setup a nodejs-express boilerplate for my new project, and this time I want to try doc-driven flow. I've checked couples of packages like `swagger-node`, `swaggerize-express` ...etc. They all provide great functionalities.

However, I don't see anything that could support incremental scaffolding when the Swagger file is updated. That means when the spec changes I have to manually check the diff and manually add/modify the new specs. That doesn't sound cool.

Does anyone could share something that is more reasonable? Thanks!!!

**Edit:**

After trying some frameworks, I decided to use [swagger-express-middleware](https://github.com/BigstickCarpet/swagger-express-middleware). This framework offers a convenient way to automatically check routes/parameters for your service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like swagger-maven-plugin to incrementally rebuild your server code, which means reading from your api definition and updating/building code as necessary.  There are SAAS products like SwaggerHub which enable this as well, by merging code and pushing to git.